# Remove Trailing Slash From String PHP

Tags: php, string

Is it possible to remove the trailing slash **`/`** from a string using PHP?

Answer (score 269, accepted):

Sure it is, simply check if the last character is a slash and then nuke that one.

```
if(substr($string, -1) == '/') {
    $string = substr($string, 0, -1);
}
```

Another (probably better) option would be using `rtrim()` - this one removes **all** trailing slashes:

```
$string = rtrim($string, '/');
```

Comment: I'd also suggest using `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` instead of `'/'`  if using file paths so it works on all platforms.

Answer (score 73):

This removes trailing slashes:

```
$str = rtrim($str, '/');
```

Comment: Note that this removes *all* trailing slashes.

Answer (score 31):

Long accepted, however in my related searches I stumbled here, and am adding for "completeness"; `rtrim()` is great, however implemented like this:

```
$string = rtrim($string, '/\\'); //strip both forward and back slashes
```

It ensures portability from ***nix** to **Windows**, as I assume this question pertains to dealing with paths.

Comment: interesting! however on my end I stumbled here regarding *routes*, not paths

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Well, the answer is somewhat presumptuous with concern to paths; the OP may have had altogether different reasons. Since "routes" typically act on "paths" (*of some sort*) it's all the same in the end :-)

Comment: In case the Op would indeed want to remove a trailing directory separator from a path, use the constant [`DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php) instead of `'/\\'`.

Comment: @Jens I'd agree, however since PHP supports \*nix and Windows paths corner cases might go untrimmed.

Comment: @NorthbornDesign: Do you have an example? You mean trimming a *nix path on Windows, and vice versa, not just native paths?

Comment: @Jens Yes, essentially. I may hardcode a path in configuration as `/foo/bar/`, meanwhile other local services on windows may yield `C:\tmp\ ` or otherwise.

Answer (score 6):

[rtrim](http://php.net/rtrim)
Use rtrim cause it respects the string doesnt end with a trailing slash

Comment: Except that it does not really remove trailing slashes, but unquotes a string.

Comment: well i missed the trailing part in the question... I made a mistake
and i specifically wrote that it removes all slashes

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is!

http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php