# Strip last "/" from a URL

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Probably a simple question but I can't seem to find the right code. Does anyone know how to strip the last / from an URL?

I got the following code that generates the url: www.mysite/inclusief/2-show-girls/

```
global $post;
        $slug = get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy, $args_incl );
        $path = $slug;

        $links[] = '<a class="fancybox-incl fancybox.ajax" title="'.$term->name.'" href="' . $path . '#inclusief1" rel="tag">' . $term->name . '</a>';
    }
```

I am trying to target a specific div ID #inclusief1. But with the last / it doesn't seem to work. Because the URL is: www.mysite/inclusief/2-show-girls/#inclusief1.

Anyone got some pointers or some other solutions?

The bigger picture: I'm trying to target a specific div ID from using fancybox. But I got a topic open for that one already. But I'm hoping that stripping some code will do the trick...

Thanks.

Comment: Is that code PHP? The `/` should not make a difference unless your server is not set up to handle the trailing slash. You can just write code to remove the last "/" from the string

Comment: Yes, It's some code from my functions.php file in my Wordpress theme.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319105/remove-trailing-slash-from-string-php

Comment: Thanks @epascarello, your link did the trick. Although Wordpress seems to be putting the "/" back in to place.

The link is now 2-show-girls#inclusief1 but when I open the link its 2-show-girls/#inclusief1 again. So this is not the solution for my problem...