# Remove a text from the end of the string

Tags: php, preg-replace

How do i remove the forward slash  i.e  `/` from the end of the string  in following kind of string

http://example.com/jobs/?fwp_cate=beauty/

I tried following code but it doesn't seem to work , rather gives some warning.

```
$term_link = "http://example.com/jobs/?fwp_cate=beauty/";
$term_link= preg_replace('~/~', '', $term_link);
```

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319105/remove-trailing-slash-from-string-php)

Comment: @DominiqueLorre  thanks a lot .... I missed the key word trailing slash while looking for the sloution /...

Answer (score 2):

Use rtrim:

```
$term_link = "http://example.com/jobs/?fwp_cate=beauty/";
$term_link= rtrim($term_link,"/");
```