# Json string with image url or Json format encoding for url

Tags: php, json

This is how I'm getting result while I'm trying to encode string in JSON format. I want that url should be in this: `http://ipaddress/Up/user_images/549279.jpg`

RESULT:

> {"result":[{"id":"42","name":"http://IPADDRESS/Up/user_images/380289.jpg"},{"id":"43","name":"http://IPADDRESS/Up/user_images/995062.jpg"},{"id":"44","name":"http://IPADDRESS/Up/user_images/171544.jpg"},{"id":"41","name":"http://IPADDRESS/Up/user_images/549279.jpg"}]}
>
> Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\jsn\PHP_Scripts\getAllEmp.php on line 26

```
//creating a blank array 
$result = array();
$r1 = array();

//looping through all the records fetched
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
    //Pushing name and id in the blank array created 
    array_push($result,array(
        "id"=>$row['userID'],
        "name"=>$ur.$row['userPic'],
    ));
} 

//Displaying the array in json format 
echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));
$r1= json_decode($result, true);
echo ($r1);
//  echo json_decode(array("result"=>$r1));

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319105/remove-trailing-slash-from-string-php  refer this, it will help

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
    //creating a blank array 
    $result = array();
    $r1=array();
    //looping through all the records fetched
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
        //Pushing name and id in the blank array created 
            array_push($result,array(
            "id"=>$row['userID'],
            "name"=>$ur.$row['userPic'],
        ));
    } 
    //Displaying the array in json format 
    $jsonData =  json_encode($result);
    echo $jsonData;  // **MODIFIED LINE**
    $r1 = json_decode($jsonData, true); // **MODIFIED LINE**
    print_r($r1);
    mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: We are not getting the result in JSON format. We are getting the same result as before and rtrim also not working

Comment: Thank you for your replay,I have found the answer  '$jsonData =  json_encode($result,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
 echo $jsonData;'