# How to redirect a URL of specific custom post type only from trailing slash to non-trailing slash?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a custom post type "used_car". I want to redirect URLs of these post types only from trailing slash to non trailing slash version. for example.

This URL is to be
https://www.carsangrah.com/used_car/delhi-ncr/faridabad/maruti-suzuki-zen-estilo-lx_857/

redirected to this URL.
https://www.carsangrah.com/used_car/delhi-ncr/faridabad/maruti-suzuki-zen-estilo-lx_857

I already checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319105) which is for redirecting all the URLs, But I want to redirect only specific URLs containing string (used_car).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Trailing Slash From String PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319105/remove-trailing-slash-from-string-php)

Comment: @DavidStockinger it will remove redirect all URLs. I want it for some specific URLs only.

Comment: Very good that you edited your question to clarify how it differs from the linked one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(used_car/.+)/$ $1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: I edited my .htaccess as below. But no success.

`# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(used_car/.+)/$ $1 [NC,R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress`

Comment: Place my rule (without `RewriteEngine on`) after `RewriteBase /`

Comment: Thanks @Croises, its working great! only thing, it is also redirecting from https to http. But, I am accepting this answer.

Comment: Thanks. But it's not this rule that redirects to http.